# Declarative AJAX "Controls" in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a reusable ajax control in MVC .NET using RAZOR.

my example is a simple ajax text box and list where the user filters the list by typing in the text box.  on the first call i would render both the text box and the list using my razor view.  on subsequent AJAX calls i would want to ONLY render the (now filtered) list.

idea 1:  use @if statement to conditionally render code.

problem:  razor does not seem to like conditionally written html.  for example it errors when a `<div>` tag is not followed by a closing `</div>`.

idea 2:  use `@section` tokens to create portions of my control and then call `RenderSection` within the same file as needed.

problem:  razor does not allow `RenderSection` to call sections in the same page

i know i can conditionally render html as strings, but i wanted to take advantage of the legibility of the razor markup and keep with development protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to output `<div>` tags in a Razor block without the corresponding `</div>` tag by surrounding it with `<text>`. The reason is that Razor uses the closing tag to know when to drag back into code-parsing mode:

```
@if (myCondition)
{
    <text>
        <div>
    </text>
}
```

As for the `Section` stuff, you might be able to achieve what you want using [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx), like this:

```
@{
Func<dynamic, object> b = @<strong>@item</strong>;
}

// ...

<span>This sentence is @b("In Bold").</span>
```

See [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) for a little more on this.